# how to be sure that QTableView.SelectedIndexes will fit the model rows order?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am using a QTableView in PyQT and I need to get the selected indexes. I use them to remove the rows in the associated model (which is a QSqlQueryModel). I am using the following code but I am sure that it's not a good idea to use the QTableView indexes with the SqlQueryModel. In most languages, there is no garanty that the model data will have the same ordering as the grid (TableView). If I ever have to sort the rows, I guess that the indexes won't fit anymore. Is there a better way to do this?

```
for item in self.TableView.selectedIndexes():
    self.SqlQueryModel.removeRow(item.row())
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the error you indicate, there is also the option that different QModelIndex may belong to the same row. So first is to get the unique rows, and then delete the rows in descending order:

```py
rows = set([index.row() for index in self.TableView.selectedIndexes()])
for row in reversed(list(rows)):
    self.SqlQueryModel.removeRow(row)
```